# Why Attribute.IsDefined not checking my custom attribute list of Myproperty

Tags: c#, reflection

The below line of code is supposed to give me the list of properties with my attribute defined on it, but it is not giving me any results.

```
var props = typeof(D).GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(MYAttribute)));
```

sample property

```
  [Serializable]
  [Table()]
  public class MYClass : IMyInterface
  { 
      [Column()]
      [MyAttribute(HeaderFields.MyValue)]
      public string MyProp { get; set; }
  }
```

When i debug i am able to see the property contains the attribute in the custom attribute list. What am i missing here?

[image]

**EDIT**

I am trying to get the properties in the below function

```
private static void MyFunction<D>(D MyObj)
  where D : IMyInterface                              
{
 var props = typeof(D).GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(MYAttribute)));
}
```

**EDIT**

The real issue was Visual studio not giving any conflict error/warning when there are attributes defined with same name in different namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you had arranged the following code:

```
[Serializable]
[Table("FooTable")]
public class MYClass : IMyInterface
{
    [Column("FooColumn")]
    [My(HeaderFields.MyValue)]
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute(object myValue) { }
}

public enum HeaderFields
{
    MyValue,
    MyAnotherValue
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
    string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

You can now get all of your properties that have defined the attribute `MyAttribute`, in the following way:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var props = typeof(MYClass).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(MyAttribute), false));

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in props)
        {
            string newLine = Environment.NewLine;

            Console.Out.WriteLine($"propertyInfo:" + newLine +
                                  $"\tName = {propertyInfo.Name}," + newLine +
                                  $"\Format = {propertyInfo}" + newLine);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Given the provided example, you should obtain such an outcome:

> propertyInfo:
>
> Name = MyProp,
>
> Format = System.String MyProp

Comment: I think, i missed a part of coded that might causing this issue. Let me edit my question. As your change prop.IsDefined(typeof(MyAttribute), false) also not giving me the result.

Comment: I think i should use the typeof(D).UnderlyingSystemType.GetProperties(). Trying that.

Comment: Actually my issue was, because there were 2 attributes defined in different namespace and Visual studio didnt give me any conflict error. Thanks for your answer.